# Skip serverless build, if correct ECR image is provided

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I might be missing something, but in my serverless.yml if I mention the correct and resolvable ECR URL, serverless deploy will still package and bundle the application. Any way to bypass the entire thing and jump directly on the deployments?

Answer (score 0):

The code won't be packaged in that case (unless you have some functions that do not use images), but Serverless Framework still needs to generate and upload CloudFormation file for your deployment, so that's probably what is happening. How long does the packaging process take in your case?